# R: rename columns with sequencial number and save the list

Tags: r

I have a dataframe named "data" which has thousands of columns whose name starts with "var":

```
var_09328, var_84894, var_83843, var_232562, var_12345, ...
```

I would need a script which renames all columns starting with "var_" with sequencial names, as:

```
column1, column2, column3, column4, column5...
```

but i need that the replacement list is saved in a data-frame like

```
New_name        Old_name
column1         var_09328
column2         var_84894
column3         var_83843
column4         var_232562
column5         var_12345
```

Does someone have any ideas? thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `df` is the data frame you have, then you can use

```
s <- names(df)
idx <- grep("^var_.*",s)
s[idx] <- paste0("column",seq_along(idx))
names(df) <- s
```

Comment: @RichScriven Thanks for pointing that out! Now I update my solution

Comment: Or `seq_along(idx)`.

Comment: It works, @ThomasIsCoding, thank you! I managed to save the new names as a new list and then to create a data.frame using the function as.data.frame :-)